# Parsing nested Json data in swift 3

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, swift3

I am getting unexpected values back when i am parsing my json data from my api, i may be doing something wrong here as i'm quite new to swift but i was getting correct values before when i was receiving one "key" but now i have added two i cannot seem to parse the values properly.

This is the json collected from the address my code is receiving, (sorry if its hard to read havn't worked out how to do line breaks yet in my ruby api)(as long as its functional im not too worried at the moment)

```
           {
    "ratings":{
    "elements":{"Ready Position":[{"description":"Neutral Grip","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Back Straight (Concave ir Convex?)","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Body Low \u0026 Feet a little more than sholder width apart","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Weight on Balls of Feet","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Head Up","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Sholder Blades Close","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Eyes Drilled","values":"1,2,3,4,5"}],"Split Step":[{"description":"Ready Position Conforms","values":"Yes,No"},{"description":"Body Position Low","values":"1,2,3,4,5"},{"description":"Legs Loaded/Prepared","values":"1,2,3,4,5"}]}
},
    "comments":{}
}
```

Now, My swift code looks like this

```
 let playerAPIurl = "http://linkcoachuat.herokuapp.com/api/v1/session/element?organisation=" + userorganisation + "&group=" + urlGroupSelected + "&sport=" + usersport
    print(playerAPIurl)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: playerAPIurl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"



    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR")
        }
        else{

            do {


                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: AnyObject]

                print(json)
```

And this is the output im getting from this print(json)

```
Optional({
    comments =     {
    };
    ratings =     {
    };
})
```

I know i shouldnt be getting anything more in the comments part, but in the ratings part there should be some data?

so after recieving the json and dealing with parsing it i need to access this part of it ["ratings"]["elements"] and after that im all good

thanks in advance and please bare in mine im very new to swift

Thanks

Comment: If you get an output at all your code is basically correct (btw. in Swift 3 a standard JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`). I suspect you are using a wrong or badly formatted URL. It's highly recommended to compose the URL with `URLComponents / URLQueryItems` because the percent encoding is handled automatically. Unrelated to the issue but you don't need an `URLRequest` because `GET` is the default. Just pass the URL

Comment: Sorry went to edit my comment but deleted it.  I tried your URL and no data is coming back.  Please check that.  I get:
{"ratings":{},"comments":{}}

Comment: Right, it wasnt my url (it inputs data from elsewhere which was inputted into the url), but it was something to do with the database and api

Comment: @Ray did my answer solve your question, if yes then accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. The url used in below code has your JSON data. This code is printing the output correctly.

```
 func testApi(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/jfccx")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }

            do {
                //create json object from data
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                    print(json)
                }

            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

[image: output]